# DBVisualizer ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000 Password expired

Tags: db2-luw, dbvisualizer

Connecting to DB2 LUW 11.5 database (running on docker)
since a few days I got the following:
An error occurred while establishing the connection:
ERRORCODE=-4214, SQLSTATE=28000 Password expired
the connection to a postgresql database via Davis works fine

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a question about admin, not about programming. Shell into the container as root, use the `chage` command to change the password expiry interval with appropriate options (if you do not want this symptom to repeat in future) , and use the `passwd` command to reset the password for the user.

Comment: chage -M 1000 db2inst1
[root@db2server ~]# chage -l db2inst1
Last password change     : Feb 28, 2021
Password expires     : Nov 25, 2023

Comment: thanks for the good hint